# I need to convert a factor to a range of numbers (1 to 0-5) in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble converting a whole number to a range of numbers in R. I have binned distances, but would like to "unbin" them.

For example, data was binned when I entered it in to Microsoft Access as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. I would like to convert these to their respective ranges in R (1 to 0-5, 2 to 5-10, 3 10-15, etc.) Is there a code to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `labels` argument to `factor`

Answer (score 1):

Use `factor`

```
factor(c(1,2,3), labels=c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15"))
```

consider this simple example where you have a vector `x` consiting of number 1,2 and 3, you can set each 'range' by using `factor`

```
> set.seed(1)
> x <- sample(1:3, 10, TRUE)
> data.frame(x, interval=factor(x, labels=c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15")))
   x interval
1  1      0-5
2  2     5-10
3  2     5-10
4  3    10-15
5  1      0-5
6  3    10-15
7  3    10-15
8  2     5-10
9  2     5-10
10 1      0-5
```

To count how many occurence has each 'range' you can use `table`

```
> table(factor(x, labels=c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15")))

  0-5  5-10 10-15 
    3     4     3
```